# Using a present or past passive form in a polite request with if

Tags: formal-language, conditionals

Which of the following forms are preferred in a formal letter, when you want to ask a client to sign your contract sooner.

> We would also be very grateful if our contract is kindly signed by Ms.
> X
>
> We would also be very grateful if our contract was kindly signed by
> Ms. X

Comment: _Would_ takes _was_ - but what's wrong with saying "...if Ms. X would kindly sign our contract"?

Comment: The use of `kindly` in both sentences is somewhat strange.  It is almost as if the writer does not understand what *kindly* means.  Are you demanding that the addressee adopts a *kind* (good-hearted, or respectful or generous) demeanor while signing?   (See definitions [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/kind).)